# How to calculate the principal value for a two-dimensional integral numerically?

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I want to calculate the principal value of following two-dimensional integral numerically
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\int_{0}^{\infty}dy\sqrt{xe^{-100x}}\sqrt{ye^{-100y}}\frac{1-e^{1000\imath(x+y)}}{(x+y)(y-0.001)}
$$
The mathematica code is

```
NIntegrate[Sqrt[x E^{-100x}]Sqrt[y E^{-100x}]((1-E^{1000I(x+y)})/(x+y))(1/(y-0.001)),{x,0,∞},{y,0,∞}]
```

The mathematica gives the following error

> Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the
>   following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly
>   oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small
>
> NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 18
>   recursive bisections in y near {y,x} ={0.000999996,0.00121927}. NIntegrate obtained 0.0509438 +0.00910859I and 0.05892024847005836` for the integral and error estimates.

How can I calculate the principal value of integral without error with NIntegrate? Actually I am encountering with this types of integrals and errors in my line of work frequently. I need a solid method to deal with such integrals.

P.S.: I examined this integral in Matlab and it gave an answer without error. What is the difference between Mathematica and Matlab in this context?

Comment: Did you get any answer at all?  I got the error but  also got the answer {1.79492*10^10}

Comment: @JoseECalderon Yes. I Do. But I am not sure that is the correct answer.

Comment: The integrand in your code is different from that in $\LaTeX$, which one is correct? (Just press Ctrl+Shift+N and check your code, the `(y-0.001)` term is in the numerator. )

Comment: @xzczd I corrected the mathematica code.

Comment: I think the ``\`` should be `/`?

Comment: @xzczd Yeah. Done.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the behavior indicated is correct: the integral diverges, and for a reason that is fairly clear.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: Disagree. It is of inerest how to show the divergence with Mathematica and how to calculate its principal value if the latter exists.

Comment: @user64492 (1) There is no question raised in this post about  computing a principal value integral. (2) There is no question raised in this post about how to programatically provide a reason for the divergence. (3) My vote to close is based on what I read in the post.

Comment: @user64494 I did corrected the code back then. Please see the code.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau (1) I corrected the post to include the principal value. (2) I don't need a reason for the divergence. It has been written in the error message. This integral describes the dynamics of a physical system. Physically, if we take care of singularities, it should not diverge. (3) I didn't get a solid answer yet. So don't be too hasty.

Comment: I'm fine with reopening then. But I suggest it get a few more changes. For one, the title remains misleading: it should be a "convergence problem" so the use of "problem" is, well, problematic.If I understand correctly, what you want is a numerical principal value integral. Which is fine, it could just be mde more clear from the outset.

Comment: Looks good-- I voted to reopen. One other request: please add links both ways to the cross-post on Wolfram Community.

Answer (score 2):

The integral under consideration diverges in view of the singular line $y=1/1000$ of the integrand. The Integrate command detects it:

```
Integrate[ Sqrt[x Exp[-100 x]] Sqrt[ y Exp[-100 x]] (1 - Exp[1000 I (x + y)])/((x + y) (y - 0.001)), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

> Integrate::idiv: Integral of (0.177245 Sqrt[y])/(-0.001+y)-((0.0414551 +0.0375163 I) E^(1000 I y) Sqrt[y])/(-0.001+y)+(3.14159 E^(100 y) y Erf[10 Sqrt[y]])/(-0.001+y)-(3.14159 E^(100 y) y Erf[10 Sqrt[(1-10 I) y]])/(-0.001+y) does not converge on {0,[Infinity]}.

Few syntax errors (e.g. `E^{-100x}`) are corrected in the above.

Even with `PrincipalValue -> True`

```
Integrate[ Sqrt[x Exp[-100 x]] Sqrt[y Exp[-100 x]] (1 - Exp[1000 I (x + y)])/((x + y) (y - 0.001)), {y,0, \[Infinity]}, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

> Integrate[
>    1/(0.001 + 1. x)
>      E^(-100 x) ((0. - 0.0993459 I) Sqrt[x] + 3.14159 x + 
>       E^(1000 I x) ((0.106478 - 0.0123898 I) Sqrt[x] - 
>          3.14159 x Cos[1000. x] + (0. + 3.14159 I) x Sin[1000. x] + 
>          FresnelC[
>            25.2313 Sqrt[
>             x]] ((3.14159 - 3.14159 I) x Cos[
>               1000. x] - (3.14159 + 3.14159 I) x Sin[1000. x]) + 
>          FresnelS[
>            25.2313 Sqrt[
>             x]] ((3.14159 + 3.14159 I) x Cos[
>               1000. x] + (3.14159 - 3.14159 I) x Sin[1000. x]))), {x, 
>     0, [Infinity]}, PrincipalValue -> True]
>   Then

```
NIntegrate[1/(0.001 + 1. x) E^(-100 x) ((0. - 0.0993459 I) Sqrt[x] + 3.14159 x +E^(1000 I x) ((0.106478 - 0.0123898 I) Sqrt[x] - 
   3.14159 x Cos[1000. x] + (0. + 3.14159 I) x Sin[1000. x] + 
   FresnelC[25.2313 Sqrt[x]] ((3.14159 - 3.14159 I) x Cos[1000. x] - (3.14159 + 3.14159 I) x Sin[1000. x]) + FresnelS[ 25.2313 Sqrt[
       x]] ((3.14159 + 3.14159 I) x Cos[1000. x] + (3.14159 - 3.14159 I) x Sin[1000. x]))), {x,  0, \[Infinity]}]
```

> 0.0257157 - 0.00922848 I

Comment: Verify.. There is a mistake in the equation. Left the y-0.001 in the numerator.

Comment: @Jose E Calderon: Thank you. The incorrect addition was deleted by me.

Comment: Which version are you in? In v9.0.1 and v8.0.4 the 2nd integral returns unevaluated with a few warning.

Comment: @xczd: I use v. 11. You are right.  Indeed, the true output is Integrate[
 1/(0.001 + 1. x)
   E^(-100 x) ((0. - 0.0993459 I) Sqrt[x] + 3.14159 x + 
    E^(1000 I x) ((0.106478 - 0.0123898 I) Sqrt[x] -  3.14159 x Cos[1000. x] + (0. + 3.14159 I) x Sin[1000. x] +  FresnelC[ 25.2313 Sqrt[ x]] ((3.14159 - 3.14159 I) x Cos[1000. x] - (3.14159 + 3.14159 I) x Sin[1000. x]) +   FresnelS[25.2313 Sqrt[ x]] ((3.14159 + 3.14159 I) x Cos[           1000. x] + (3.14159 - 3.14159 I) x Sin[1000. x]))), {x, 
  0, \[Infinity]}, PrincipalValue -> True] Thank you. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the "PrincipalValue" option works for two-dimensional Integrate not NIntegrate. This would do.

Answer (score 1):

The integrand has a singularity in $y=0.001$, but also have terms than can be separated and integrated firstly wrt x. The integrad is:

```
 Sqrt[x Exp[-100 x]] Sqrt[y Exp[-100 y]] (1 - Exp[1000 I (x + y)])/((x + y) (y - 0.001))
```

Now, and with $y\geq0$, first integrate the real part:

```
 Assuming[y >= 0, Integrate[(1 - Cos[1000 (x + y)]) Sqrt[x] Exp[-50. x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]]

 (*0.00250663 + 0.0000182432 Cos[1000. y] + 0.0000212049 Sin[1000. y]*)
```

with respect to $y$ and taking into account the singularity at 0.001:

```
NIntegrate[1/(-0.001+ y) Sqrt[y] Exp[-50 y] (0.0025066282746310014 + 
0.000018243204055544903 Cos[1000. y] + 
0.000021204895736310885 Sin[1000. y]), {y, 0, .001, \[Infinity]},
Method-> "DoubleExponential", MaxRecursion -> 200]

 (*0.000567425*)
```

If we do the same for the imaginary part:

```
Assuming[y >=0, -I Integrate[( Sin[1000 (x + y)]) Sqrt[ x] Exp[-50. (x)], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]] 

(*-I (0.0000212049 Cos[1000 y] - 0.0000182432 Sin[1000 y])*)

NIntegrate[1/(-0.001 + y) Sqrt[y]
Exp[-50 y] (-I (0.000021204895736310888 Cos[1000 y] - 
0.00001824320405554491 Sin[1000 y])), {y, 0, .001, \[Infinity]},
Method -> "DoubleExponential", MaxRecursion -> 200]

(*2.21313*10^-6 I*)
```

The value seems to be 0.000567425+2.21313$10^{-6}i$

Comment: @ José Antonio Díaz Nava :  This is another task than the stated one because you integrate  with respect to $y$ from $0.001$ to $\infty$.

Comment: @user64494 You are right. I have just edited to take into account the singularity in $y$

Comment: @ José Antonio Díaz Nava : Can you kindly comment your code, especially the following places {y, 0, 0.001, \[Infinity]} and "SymbolicProcessing" -> 5? A good code is a commented code. I am not an expert in Mathematica. TIA.

Comment: Basically you can include the singularities in the integration domain. The number in SymbolicProcessing option tells Mathematica how many seconds for preprocessing the integrand symbolically. Please write my name correctly.

Comment: @ José Antonio Díaz Navas : I am very sorry for the incorrect spelling of your name. Thank you. I did  find it (i.e. "Basically you can include the singularities in the integration domain" )  in http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html . However, the integral under consideration diverges. Is a certain generalized value of it calculated in your answer?

Comment: @ José Antonio Díaz Navas : Don't you miss the left parenthesis  in /(x + y) (y -0.001))?

Comment: @user64494 I will check it. If I obtain a non useful answer I will remove my post.

Comment: @user64494 Please, take a look now

Comment: @ José Antonio Díaz Navas : However, the integral under consideration diverges. Is a certain generalized value of it calculated in your answer?

Comment: You ask me the same before. What you mean? MMA does not return any error on NIntegrate

Comment: @ José Antonio Díaz Navas : The result of a command with complicated options may not be reliable, may it?

Comment: @user64494 maybe we need an expert at this time.